# JavaScript make if condition while creating HTML mark up in JS

Tags: javascript

I am creating dynamic HTML content via JS to display table of users

I am getting the data array from the local storage and loop on it and create markup variable and insert it to the HTML

I need to make if condition if the user age bigger than 50 so make the background of the row red

This is my code

```
function displayUsers() {
    let markUp = ``;

    for (let i = 0; i < usersContainer.length; i++) {
        markUp += `<tr><td>${usersContainer[i].no}</td><td>${usersContainer[i].name}</td><td>${usersContainer[i].email}</td><td>${usersContainer[i].tel}</td><td>${usersContainer[i].dob}</td><td>${usersContainer[i].rmk}</td><td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteUser(${i})"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td></tr>`;
    }

    $('#tableBody').html(markUp);
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Split the "row", add that `if`, combine the parts, use in `.html()`.

Comment: can you modify the code please? @Andreas

Comment: No -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: HTML/CSS/JavaScript is one of the easiest thing to learn on the internet - just search a tutorial for each of those. If you can't do this then hire a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend calculating the `age` based on `dob`, and then setting the color based on the condition, like this:

```js
function displayUsers() {
    let markUp = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < usersContainer.length; i++) {

        // Format the DB to get the age.
        const dob = usersContainer[i].dob;
        const age = (your age calculation code here based on dob);
        
        markUp += `<tr style="background:${age > 50 ? '#FF0000' : '#FFFFFF' }">`;
        markUp += `<td>${usersContainer[i].no}</td>`;
        markUp += `<td>${usersContainer[i].name}</td>`;
        markUp += `<td>${usersContainer[i].email}</td>`;
        markUp += `<td>${usersContainer[i].tel}</td>`;
        markUp += `<td>${usersContainer[i].dob}</td>`;
        markUp += `<td>${usersContainer[i].rmk}</td>`;
        markUp += `<td>`;
        markUp += `<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteUser(${i})">`;
        markUp += `<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>`;
        markUp += `</button>`;
        markUp += `</td>`;
        markUp += `</tr>`;
    }

    $('#tableBody').html(markUp);
}
```

Comment: You can get the `age` based on the `dob` by doing something along these lines. As you did not include the format of the `dob`, I leave that portion to you: https://www.javatpoint.com/calculate-age-using-javascript